# Why am I having Errors on the Method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors in the setInitialQuantity method declaration, does anyone mind taking a look?

```
public class Invoice
{
    private int quantity;
    private String partNum;
    private String partDesc;
    private double unitPrice;


    //constructor 
    public Invoice ( int initialQuantity, String partNumber, String partDescript, double unitPrice)
    {
        public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
        {
            quantity = initialQuantity;
        }   
    }//end Invoice constructor
}
```

Errors:

```
javac Invoice.java
Invoice.java:16: illegal start of expression
    public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
    ^
Invoice.java:16: illegal start of expression
    public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
           ^
Invoice.java:16: ';' expected
    public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
                                  ^
Invoice.java:16: ';' expected
    public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
                                                        ^
4 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a method inside another (or a Concstructor) in Java, move it outside the constructor but inside the class.

```
public class Invoice
{
    private int quantity;
    private String partNum;
    private String partDesc;
    private double unitPrice;


    //constructor 
    public Invoice ( int initialQuantity, String partNumber, String partDescript, double unitPrice)
    {
    }//end Invoice constructor

public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
    {
            quantity = initialQuantity;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define method inside another method.

```
//constructor     
public Invoice(int initialQuantity,String partNumber,String partDescript,double unitPrice)
{
   this.quantity=initialQuantity;
   this.partNum=partNumber;
   this.partDesc=partDescript;
   this.unitPrice=unitPrice;
}   
public void setInitialQuantity(int initialQuantity)
{
    quantity = initialQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Cosntructor to:

```
 public Invoice ( int initialQuantity, String partNumber, String partDescript, double unitPrice)
    {      
       quantity = initialQuantity;         
    }//end Invoice constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have method within constructor, might be you are looking for something like:

```
public class Invoice
{
    private int quantity;
    private String partNum;
    private String partDesc;
    private double unitPrice;


    //constructor 
    public Invoice ( int initialQuantity, String partNumber, String partDescript, double unitPrice)
    {
        quantity = initialQuantity;
        partNum = partNumber;
        partDesc = partDescript;
        unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }//end Invoice constructor

    public void setInitialQuantity ( int initialQuantity )
    {
        quantity = initialQuantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define 'setInitialQuantity' outside you constructor and then call it from you constructor. something like this:

```
//constructor          
public Invoice (int initialQuantity, String partNumber, String partDescript, double unitPrice)
{   
   setInitialQuantity(initialQuantity);     
}//end Invoice constructor

public void setInitialQuantity (int initialQuantity)
{
   quantity = initialQuantity;
}
```